# Clonar una tabla y clonar campos de texto dentro de la misma

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema al clonar una tabla completa en JavaScript: al presionar el botón que me permite clonar la tabla se me desactivan los botones que me permiten clonar campos de texto dentro de la misma; y viceversa: si presiono los botones dentro de la tabla que me clonan los campos de texto, se me desactivan los botones que me permiten clonar la tabla.

La imagen siguiente indica cómo son las tablas que deseo implementar:

[image: la imagen siguiente indica como son las tablas que deseo implementar]

Y éste es el código que utilizo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  tabla = $('#tabla');

  $('#agregartabla').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents(".cl1").clone().appendTo("div#cl0").find(':text').val('');
  });

  $(".eliminartabla").live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".cl1").remove();
  });

  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum)
      .attr('name', 'name' + newNum).find(':text').val('');

    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#btnDel').attr('enabled', '');
    if (newNum == 10)
      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
    
    $('#input' + num).remove();
    $('#btnAdd').attr('enabled', '');
    if (num - 1 == 0)
      $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cl0">
  <div id="cl1" class="cl1">
    <input type="button" value="Agregar" id="agregartabla">
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar" class="eliminartabla">
    <table width="70%" border="2" id="tabla">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ol>
            <li>ARTICULO<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" /></li>
          </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ol>
            <div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
              <li>MARCA<input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" /></li>
            </div>
          </ol>
          <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="AGREGAR MARCA" />
          <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="BORRAR MARCA" />
        </td>
      </tr><br>
    </table><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No compartas el código en una imagen, hazlo copiando y pegando el código con etiqueta `code`.

Comment: Puedo reproducir el primer fallo: si se clona la tabla, se "desactivan" los botones de dentro de la tabla; pero no el segundo fallo: si pulso en los botones de dentro de la tabla, los botones de clonar no se desactivan.

Comment: Aparte de eso, usas una versión muy antigua de jQuery y métodos que se consideran obsoletos y han sido eliminados de versiones modernas. Quizás deberías replantearte actualizar el código.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa que tengo es la siguiente, pero tiene un pequeño problema de duplicación de la fila de tabla anidada interna, que al clonar esta fila interna se clona igualmente en todas las tablas externas agregadas.

```js
$(function(){
                $(document).on('click',"#agregartablauno" , function(){                
                $("#tablauno tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                    .append('<td class="eliminartablauno"><input type="button" value="ELIMINAR"/></td>')
                    .appendTo("#tablauno");         
                });
                
                $(document).on("click",".eliminartablauno",function(){
                var parent = $(this).parent();
                $(parent).remove();
                });
           
                $(this).on('click', ".agregartablados" , function(){                
                $(".tablados tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                    .append('<td class="eliminartablados"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>')
                    .appendTo(".tablados");         
                });

                $(document).on("click",".eliminartablados",function(){
                var parent = $(this).parent();
                $(parent).remove();
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>I</title>

    <script>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><center>
       <table id="tablauno" align="center" >
         <tr>
           <td>
             ARTICULO <input type="text" name="txtarticulo" size=32 />
           </td>                                         
           <td>
            <table class="tablados">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <td>MARCA</td>                                
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                   <tr id="fila-base">
                      <td><input id="txtmarca" name="txtmarca" type="text" /></td>                                
                   </tr>
                  </tbody>
            </table> 
            <input class="agregartablados" type="button" value="+" /> 
          </td>            
        </tr>
       </table>
       <input id="agregartablauno" type="button" value="AGREGAR"> <br><br>
    </center></body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedo reproducir el primer problema: si se clona la tabla, se "desactivan" los botones de dentro de la tabla, pero no al revés como dices en la pregunta. Me voy a centrar en ese fallo.

El error ocurre por una serie de problemas:

- Cuando añades/borras campos de la tabla, cuentas el número de campos clonados y entonces intentas añadir detrás el campo con ID `"#input" + número de campos clonados` o borrar el campo con ID `"#input" + número de campos clonados` respectivamente. Por eso funciona cuando hay una sola tabla: el número de campos clonados coincide con el número de campos disponibles y entonces los IDs a añadir/borrar coinciden sin problemas. Pero cuando hay más de una tabla, cuentas el número de campos clonados que es mayor que los IDs de los campos de las tablas  (ver problema sobre IDs duplicados abajo). La solución consistiría en no contar el número total de campos clonados, sino el número de campos clonados **dentro de esa tabla en concreto**. Y luego añadir y borrar pero sólo dentro de esa tabla en concreto.
- Tienes IDs repetidos. No los tienes al principio, pero una vez clonas las tablas, clonas los campos con sus respectivos IDs y aparece el problema de los IDs repetidos. Inicialmente pensaba que el problema era éste y, aunque realmente no lo es, el problema en parte se deriva de esto.
- Estás usando una versión de jQuery (1.7) que es anticuada y que incluye métodos (que usas) que se consideran obsoletos y que se han eliminado de versiones más modernas (p.e. [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)). Deberías cambiar a una versión de jQuery más moderna, actualizar tu código y usar funciones más adecuadas como [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Esto realmente no es la causa del problema, pero es algo muy recomendable, incluso manteniendo la versión de jQuery podrías usar `on`.
- No se están asociando los controladores de eventos correctamente para los botones de "Agregar Marca" y "Borrar marca". Esto ocurre porque se están asociando antes de que se clonen y entonces los clones no tienen esos controladores asociados. Esto se podría solucionar usando `live` en lugar de `click` (aunque no lo recomiendo por el punto anterior, sería mejor eventos delegados con `on`); otra opción sería pasando el parámetro `true` al `clone` (para que así se mantengan los eventos asociados al evento clonado)

He cambiado un poco tu código para adaptarlo a lo que digo arriba:

- Quitando los IDs que se van a duplicar y sustituyéndolos por clases.
- Cambiando `live` por `on`.
- Usando eventos delegados.
- Limitando el ámbito de las cuentas a la tabla sobre la que se está operando en lugar de todo el documento.

Con esos cambios, el código se vería así y ya funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on('click', '.agregartabla', function() {
    $(this).parents(".cl1").clone().appendTo("div#cl0").find(':text').val('');
  });

  $("body").on('click', ".eliminartabla", function() {
    $(this).closest(".cl1").remove();
  });

  $("body").on("click", '.btnAdd', function() {
    var tabla = $(this).closest(".tabla");
    var num = tabla.find('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
    var newElem = tabla.find('.input' + num).clone().attr('class', 'input' + newNum + ' clonedInput');

    newElem.children(':first').attr('class', 'name' + newNum)
      .attr('name', 'name' + newNum).find(':text').val('');

    tabla.find('.input' + num).after(newElem);
    tabla.find('.btnDel').attr('enabled', '');
    if (newNum == 10)
      tabla.find('.btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $("body").on("click", '.btnDel', function() {
    var tabla = $(this).closest(".tabla");
    var num = tabla.find('.clonedInput').length;
    
    tabla.find('.input' + num).remove();
    tabla.find('.btnAdd').attr('enabled', '');
    if (num - 1 == 0)
      tabla.find('.btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cl0">
  <div id="cl1" class="cl1">
    <input type="button" value="Agregar" class="agregartabla">
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar" class="eliminartabla">
    <table width="70%" border="2" class="tabla">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ol>
            <li>ARTICULO<input type="text" name="name2" class="name2" /></li>
          </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ol>
            <div class="input1 clonedInput">
              <li>MARCA<input type="text" name="name3" class="name3" /></li>
            </div>
          </ol>
          <input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="AGREGAR MARCA" />
          <input type="button" class="btnDel" value="BORRAR MARCA" />
        </td>
      </tr><br>
    </table><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: El problema adicional que tenia en el código anterior es que los botones de eliminar en las tablas anidadas llevaban a eliminar por completo los div de id´s c10 y c11, no permitiendo renovar las tabla ni sus campos, ¿como podría implementar que los botones de eliminar en las tablas anidadas se desactiven o se oculten cuando solamente quede un elemento, en este caso diría que quede un objeto de la <div class="input1 clonedInput"> o un objeto de la <div id="cl0">.

Answer (score 0):

Para clonar un Elemento HTML, en Vanilla JavaScript se proporciona el método [Node.cloneNode(deep)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

```
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const clonedTable = table.cloneNode(true);
```

Para agregar un Elemento HTML después de un Elemento HTML, en Vanilla JavaScript se proporciona el método [Element.insertAdjacentElement(pos, text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement).

```
const el = document.querySelector('#container');
el.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clonedTable);
```