# ¿Cómo autogenerar un arreglo asociativo en HTML para pasar a PHP con $_POST?

Tags: php, html, array, post

Tengo el siguiente formulario HTML https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/87632/50098, como se muestra en el gráfico, lo utilizo de la siguiente manera, articulo es el name del primer input, y es del tipo arreglo, el arreglo está compuesto por los input marca también del tipo arreglo, para cada marca se registra existencias y valor estas últimas pueden estar como elementos del arreglo marca, los botones que se ven de signo (+) incrementan los inputs del arreglo marca, los botones de signo(-), eliminan el input marca.
El botón AGREGAR me incrementa los input articulo, con sus respectivos input marca con los botones de signo (+ y -) que por defecto aparecerá uno, (el signo(-) aparece cuando hay más de dos inputs marca) respectivos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un formulario que va clonando inputs, la cuestión es que quiero pasar los datos registrados en los inputs a través de POST, a una base de datos que tiene los campos de: articulo, marca, existencias y valor, como un tipo de arreglo asociativo tomando el arreglo ya formado desde el formulario HTML a través de un submit, en PHP una alternativa para formar arreglos es usando la notación de corchetes en HTML, quiero generar a través de los inputs que tengo, un array asociativo para que se procese el formulario en el lado del servidor y creo que para lo que tengo en mente el arreglo se distribuiría de la siguiente manera:

```html
Array ( [articulo] => Array (
    [marca1] => ( [existencias] => 2 [valor] => 200 ) 
      [marca2] => ( [existencias] => 4 [valor] => 400 )   ) 
[enviar] => Enviar      )
```

He realizado intentos de que me quede de esta forma usando la notación de corchetes en HTML pero no me queda, con  print_r($_POST);  he realizado las pruebas y no sé, hasta donde es posible hacerlo de esta manera o hay otras alternativas de registrar estos datos como un arreglo.

```html
<form method="POST" action="ArchivoPOST.php">
    <input type="text" name="articulo[]" placeholder="articulo" />
    <input type="text" name="articulo[][marca]" placeholder="marca" />
    <input type="text" name="articulo[][existencia]" placeholder="existencia" />
    <input type="text" name="articulo[][valor]" placeholder="valor" />
<input name="enviar" type="submit" value=" Enviar ">
</form>
```

El código anterior revisando con con  print_r($_POST);  deberia quedar de la siguiente forma, pero no queda asi y no encuentro el fallo.

```html
Array ( [articulo] => Array (
    [marca1] => ( [existencias] => 2 [valor] => 200 ) 
              [marca2] => ( [existencias] => 4 [valor] => 400 )   ) 
[enviar] => Enviar      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" action="process.php">
<input type="text" name="form[articulo][nombre]" placeholder="articulo" />
<input type="text" name="form[articulo][marca]" placeholder="marca" />
<input type="text" name="form[articulo][existencia]" placeholder="existencia" />
<input type="text" name="form[articulo][valor]" placeholder="valor" />
```

El arreglo resultante es este:

```
Array ( [articulo] => Array ( [nombre] => a [marca] => b [existencia] => 12 [valor] => 13 ) )
```

Creo que era lo que querias si quieres perfecionarlo y que la primera llave sea el nombre del artículo solo debes comenzar los nombres de cada campo como form[articulo][propiedad] donde articulo es el nombre del articulo, y propiedad puede ser "marca", "valor" o "existencia". Tienes que jugar un poco con javascript para lograr esto último.

Comment: si eso era lo que queria que "articulo" sea un arreglo y tenga las propiedades de marca y valor dentro del mismo.